# Bash trap not deleting folder

Tags: bash, shell

Take a look at the following code

```
cleanuptempdir() {
  echo "# Delete temp folder"
  echo "rm -Rf $tempdir"
  rm -Rf "$tempdir"
}

trap cleanuptempdir EXIT
tempdir2=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$tempdir2"
login # The login function is executing a git clone and saving it into the tempdir2
rm -Rf "$tempdir2"

tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
echo "# Created temporary folder $tempdir"
cd "$tempdir"
# Do some code
```

In this scneario i get the error `Directory not empty` when the execution of my code is finished. What am i doing wrong here and how can i prevent this error from happening?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error described.

Comment: Maybe it helps to insert a simple `cd` in your function `cleanuptempdir` to leave the directory before deleting it.

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version of `rm` do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus It is weird on my machine it is working, but on the machine of my colleague i get this problem. It's a work related problem so i will send an update on Monday

Comment: Definitely check if your colleague is using WSL or FUSE or something that is close but not exactly like a standard linux/unix dir

Comment: @Cyrus My colleague uses rm (GNU coreutils) 8.30

Comment: @Cyrus Seems like my setup is using version 8.32 of rm

Comment: @Cyrus Updated to 8.32 , still not working

Comment: @Cyrus Inserting the cd worked! Hooray! I don't really understand why it is working on my machine then but happy now that i have fixed it.